# QUOTENAME() with parenthesis, curly brackets, angle brackets, or grave accents

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

While reading the documentation for [QUOTENAME()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), I see that it supports a variety of delimiter characters:

- Square brackets - [] (default)
- Parenthesis - ()
- Curly brackets - {}
- Angle brackets - <>
- Single quotes - '
- Double quotes - "
- Grave accents - `

In addition to wrapping the content in opening and closing delimiters, QUOTENAME() *appears to* double up any contained characters that match the closing delimiter.  For example: `QUOTENAME('matrix[2][3]')` yields `[matrix[2]][3]]]` and `QUOTENAME('cell(2)(3)', '(')` yields `(cell(2))(3)))`.

While I understand the usage of single quotes, double quotes, and square brackets to delimit identifiers and text values (primarily when constructing dynamic SQL), I am not sure what use the other forms might have.

Are there any places in SQL Server syntax where parenthesis, curly bracket, angle bracket, or grave accent delimited content has any special meaning?  Are there any languages (XML, JSON, etc.) outside of SQL where those other forms might be useful? Such cases would have to recognize the doubled character as an escape.

This is more a question of interest rather than a particular problem that I am trying to solve.

Comment: The docs do not say that *In addition to wrapping the content in opening and closing delimiters, QUOTENAME() will double up any contained characters that match the closing delimiter* . It only says *Returns a Unicode string with the delimiters added to make the input string a valid SQL Server delimited identifier*. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16. Parenthesis have special meaning in function calls and for expressing expressions generally. I'm not aware anything special for curly or angle brackets, or grave accents.

Comment: Personally I can think of no situations whatever where it is usually to have any such strange identifiers with any of these types of characters, for any reason whatever, inside or outside of sql server (have I made myself clear?!) - the only reason I can imagine doing so is if I get crazy data that is already like this which I cannot alter, or "the business" tells me I must, or perhaps for pranks. But I shall be interested to hear other responses...

Comment: I associate backticks with MySQL rather than SQL Server. I think a lot of these have been added somewhat recently. Here is the BOL for 2005 (which only lists three options) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms176114(v=sql.90)

Comment: The only thing I've ever used this for in SQL Server, in addition to the default `[]` is with double quotes when building string for exporting via csv or reporting. Probably some delimiters are of use with json or exist only for compatability.

Comment: @topsail - Granted. The "double up" part was from experimentation, not the documentation, but it was consistent across all of the cases I tested. I didn't try feeding it the entire character set, so it may do other things for certain special characters

Comment: LOL. The additional characters were added to the documentation by the community - specifically  [@Larnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu) so may well have been in the product for ages before that  https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/commit/d54d147438d8e013b5c81ceac0b1a6250648fea1

Comment: @MartinSmith Perhaps some things are best left undocumented or documented as undefined.

Comment: yeah maybe the edit has ended up turning something that they didn't particularly want to document/support into a documented feature

Comment: "Open source the docs!" they said. "It will be fun!" they said.